# How can I loop through a table skipping every 11th row while doing something on every 10th loop?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my thought process of how I think it should work.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) && ($row % 11 != 0)) {
        $counter++;
        if ($counter % 10 == 0) {
         // Do something.
        }
    }
}
```

Example of how it should work:

Row  1 = Counter  1
Row  2 = Counter  2
Row  3 = Counter  3
Row  4 = Counter  4
Row  5 = Counter  5
Row  6 = Counter  6
Row  7 = Counter  7
Row  8 = Counter  8
Row  9 = Counter  9
Row 10 = Counter 10
Row 11 = Skip
Row 12 = Counter 11
Row 13 = Counter 12
Row 14 = Counter 13
Row 15 = Counter 14
Row 16 = Counter 15
Row 17 = Counter 16
Row 18 = Counter 17
Row 19 = Counter 18
Row 20 = Counter 19
Row 21 = Counter 20
Row 22 = Skip
Row 23 = Counter 21
etc.

For further reference, here is the full piece of code I've written to remind users on my web-store that if they have 10 tickets in their cart, they'll get the next one free if they add it. Thanks Jakar

```
$fancyCounter = 1;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $rawCounter++;
        if ($rawCounter % 11 !== 0) {
            $fancyCounter++;
        }
        else {
            $fancyCounter = 1;
        }
    }
}
$result->close();

if ($fancyCounter % 11 == 0) {
    $freeTicketAvailable = 1;
} else {
    $freeTicketAvailable = 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the rows other than every 10th and 11th?

Comment: Iterate over just the fetched results using while and put the count increment at the top of the loop body.  Drop the 11 and 10 row conditions into if blocks inside the loop.  Continue; when mod 11 is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, there is a `$rawCounter` which counts the rows iterated and a `$fancyCounter` which keeps the row count just how you posted.

```
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
     $rawCounter++;
     if ($rawCounter%11!==0){
         $fancyCounter++;
     } 
     if ($rawCounter%10===0){
         //Do Something
     }
}
```

[Here is an example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fd2b5204875b3c8f2231d9a513565cd81522a56) that give your example output.

If you need the row number and the counter number separate, you could also use a `$counter` and a `$skipCount`, and always increment `$counter` and only increment `$skipCount` on `$counter%11==0` and to get the counter count you want (ie `Row 12 = Counter 11, Row 23 = Counter 21`), you'd use `echo "Row {$counter} = Counter ".($counter-$skipCount)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php

$counter = 1;

while ($counter <= 33) {

    if ($counter % 10 == 0) {
        // On 10.
        echo "Do Something<br/>";
    } else if ($counter % 11 == 0) {
        // On 11.
        echo "Skip<br/>";
    } else {
        // Other numbers.
        echo $counter . "<br/>";
    }
    $counter++;
}

?>
```

You need to replace the condition inside the `while();` to suit you.

**Output**

`1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Do Something
Skip
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
Do Something
21
Skip
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
Do Something
31
32
Skip`

Comment: The example output has `Row 12 = Counter 11, Row 23 = Counter 21`. With your code, the counter and and row number will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. You were trying to divide an array ($row) by a number in your while condition, which is probably undefined even in PHP ;)

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  
    $skipCounter = 0;
    $tenCounter = 0;
    $counter = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ++$skipCounter;
        if ($skipCounter == 11) {
          $skipCounter = 0;
          continue;
        } 
        ++$counter
        ++$tenCounter;
        echo "Counter: ".$counter;
        if ($tenCounter  ==  10) {
           $tenCounter = 0;
           echo "Do something";
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: The example output has `Row 12 = Counter 11, Row 23 = Counter 21`. With your code, the counter and and row number will be the same.

Comment: Thanks man, this is along the lines of what I want but I'm not sure it quite works. Basically I want to give a free item for every 10 items purchased and I want to let the customer know that if they have 10 items that they are eligible for a free item.

I've already got it so the discount applies when they have 11 items but I wan't to let them know if they're one short.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, turns out I didn't understand the question. The accepted answer seems perfect. To add a little value, I updated my answer to avoid  the divisions. which is more code but should run a little faster.